# smith normal from / abelian group structure.

Tags: abstract-algebra

compute the invariants and write down the structure of the abelian group with generators (x_1, x_2 , x_3) subject to.

2x_2 - x_3 = 0, -3x_1 + 8x_2 + 3x_3 = 0, 2x_1 - 4x_2 - x_3 = 0

the matrix of constraints is.

```
(0  2 -1) 
(-3 8  3)
(2 -4 -1)
```

i obtain the smith normal from by performing in order. C2+2*C3, R2+3*R1, R3-R1, switch C1 with C3, C2+5*C3, R3+4*R2, C3-3*C2 and then multiply everything with -1 and end up with the matrix

```
(1 0 0)
(0 1 0)
(0 0 10).
```

so the group is isomorphic to Z/Z x Z/Z x Z/10Z = Z/10Z

This is incorrect according to my book, it should be Z/2Z. Where do i go wrong?

Comment: Something must be wrong: your matrix of constraints has determinant equal to $\;10\;$ so the (quotient) group **indeed** is isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\;$...either you miscopied something, or you looked at the wrong quetion's answer.

Comment: I have checked several times, the problem is presented exactly as in my book, and i am looking at the right questions answer. Guess the author has made a typo, thanks for checking.